# Enable YouTube Support

Tags: feature-request, youtube

Often, a YouTube video would complement an already great answer. For example, [this MythBuster video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_OXM4mr_i0) would make a great addition to [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/303/can-microwaved-water-explode/306#306). As they say, seeing is believing. It's only one example amongst many. It is possible to have YouTube support enabled to enhance user experience?

**Note:** If it does get implement, YouTube videos will get threaded the same way as any outgoing links: they are nice, but the answer *must* be hosted here most and foremost.

Comment: I am undecided, on one hand YT links provide great content, on the other it's **never** to be considered reference. All in all I think we shouldn't allow that.

Comment: @Sklivvz: You can say the exact same thing of most images: very few of them are going to be references. Yet, we allow them. Videos, like images, provide great visual support, and as far I'm concerned that is enough. References are not everything.

Comment: That true. However I phear youtube style comments.

Comment: @Sklivvz: We will just have to smite them. Hard.

Comment: You can post a hyperlink into Youtube already and explain what it links to. Isn't that enough?

Comment: @Paul: Embed videos require less clicking (and look less slapdash).

Answer (score 4):

I'm very concerned the video "answers" would dominate the site, as they are very least-common-denominator.

I'd rather have the text (and a judicious image or diagram) dominate.

You can already *link* to YouTube, which should be sufficient for now.

Comment: To me posting 'just' a video is just like posting a bare link. You've to explain how it helps prove your point and what we can learn from it. Failing to do so should result in your answer getting converted to a comment. I don't see why Youtube links shouldn't get the same treatment as regular images though, given they produce nearly the same result.

Comment: @ivo even if it is video and 3 paragraphs, the video will DOMINATE everything else. Not in a good way.

Comment: Well I can't exactly prove or disprove it, but I'm **skeptical** about that claim. But I guess its useless to argue about it :-)

Answer (score 3):

*Seeing is believing* is a good argument against video support. We don't want to have people believe claims because they see a nice illustration but because there's convincing evidence.

Comment: Fine. Visual support is still useful. Example: [Applied Kinesiology.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Piu75P8sxTo)

Comment: I don't think it is desirable either, to have people believe textual evidence for lack of a better alternative.

Answer (score 2):

YouTube support in questions may be convenient for establishing notability - I used a youtube link in [Did ninjas use Pythagoras' theorem to determine the depth of moats?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7642/did-ninjas-use-pythagoras-theorem-to-determine-the-depth-of-moats) to demonstrate that a claim is being made.

I also would have liked embedded YouTube for [Is sponsoring a child responsible for people going to university in Mongolia?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/40702/is-sponsoring-a-child-responsible-for-people-going-to-university-in-mongolia)

Answer (score 0):

## YouTube is NOT a stable or often *legal* source to save/provide video.

- **Videos are removed every minute of every day with no reason or warning.**
- For those unfamiliar with YouTube removal process, it requires 0 effort.
- I can go to your YouTube channel right now with 0 proof and claim copyright
  infringement.
- **YouTube policy is delete the video first ask questions never** (not totally true you can fight back after it's deleted but it's an uphill battle you don't want to fight).

## Solution

If there is a more reliable service to upload videos this would make sense. For example:

## http://www.archive.org

**Archive.org because it is officially a museum and archive, follows slightly different *grey area* rules**

**If a diligent person wants to edit out only the relevant parts of the video for educational purposes only!** Archive.org *might* consider this to be something of value within their museum guidelines. It should also link back to SE Skeptics and have the question itself mirrored on Archive.org. This minimizes a chance of an information loss for future generations.

Comment: This “answer” assumes the OP is the one uploading to YouTube, and is little more than a rant about YouTube.

Answer (score -2):

Videos frequently have sound with them, and that can be a problem in several venues.  It's disruptive if one is on the site during break time at work.  It's potentially annoying if one is on the site late at night when other family members are trying to sleep.  Overall, I consider websites that have sound a generally bad idea,

A hyperlink to a video is fine.  The reader can then either follow up or not.

Another question is the storage involved.  Text takes very little storage, and pictures don't take that much compared to videos.  I don't know if this is a consideration, but it might be.

Comment: If sound is an issue, don't press play. Simple, really. And storage isn't an issue. I called my suggestion YouTube support for a reason...

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the nature of supporting YT clips. You dont store the content, only a link to it which gets embedded *from youtube*.